# Heroku, addons not recognizing verified account

Tags: heroku

I've verified my account in Heroku by entering my billing information. When I visit http://heroku.com/confirm, it tells me "Your account is already verified".

However, when I run a command to add an add-on, such as `heroku addons:add custom_domains`, I get this error:

```
-----> Adding custom_domains to uplate... failed
 !     Please verify your account to install this add-on
 !     For more information, see http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/billing
 !     Confirm now at https://heroku.com/confirm
```

Also, when I click on any "Verify" link on the website (like on the add-on pages), I just get redirected to the same page I was on, but it keeps telling me to verify.

Am I missing something? This is my first app on Heroku so I am still a little confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're certainly not doing anything wrong. To make sure it's fresh;

```
heroku auth:logout
heroku addons:add custom_domains < This will prompt your to enter your heroku credentials
```

I have seen similar reports of verified accounts not showing as verified - this was actually when a client was trying to scale their dynos and it kept getting stuck in the 'verify' lookp in which case you'll be better off contacting heroku support.

Comment: Well, this solved the verification issue, however now it's telling me that I don't have access to the application that I just created on heroku. It's not listed in "My Apps", but I can access it in my browser and push changes to it without any problem.

Comment: If you login to heroku using the credentials you just used then you should see your application in My Apps - if not, it's definitely a question for support. If you do `heroku info` in your application does the OWNER value match the login you're using to Heroku.com. It sounds like there could be multiple heroku accounts floating around here to me.

Comment: running `heroku info` gives me the same message - "You do not have access to <appname>". I do have another account with Heroku that I abandoned a long time ago because it was for a project that didn't happen. If that's the cause of the problem, what could I do to wipe my computer clean of everything Heroku, and start fresh? This is on OS X 10.7 by the way.

Comment: to 'get rid' of heroku you would just delete your ~/.heroku folder - that is where it stores credentials that the `heroku` command uses. It will recreate it when you use the command again, see how that works for you? ps make sure your heroku gem is up to date.

Comment: See the answer I posted... I guess I was still logged in with my old credentials when I created the app, setting its owner to my old login stuffs. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was able to solve this issue just by doing a `heroku auth:logout` followed by a `heroku auth:login`.

Answer (score 0):

John Beynon answered my original question. However, I then was getting the "You do not have access to ". This was because I was still logged in with the credentials from another account when I first created the app. To solve this, I ran two commands:

```
heroku sharing:add <myemail> // adds a collaborator to the app
heroku sharing:transfer <myemail> // transfers ownership
```

You can then optionally run:

```
heroku sharing:remove <oldemail>
```

To remove the old e-mail address from the app.