# adding sendgrid addon to my heroku django app

Tags: heroku, sendgrid

I have a django app hosted on heroku.I am using django-registration which sends validation email to a registering user.So ,I tried to add the sendgrid addon using

`heroku addons:add sendgrid`

but this fails with the following message

```
Adding sendgrid:starter on myapp... failed
 !    Please verify your account to install this add-on
 !    For more information, see http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/billing
 !    Verify now at https://heroku.com/verify
```

It seems to go to a page which asks for my credit card info..Unfortunately I don't have one..Is it still possible for me to get this addon without having a credit card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Dev Center article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification), you have to add a credit card to use free add-cons. Once that's done, you [may have to log out and back in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846491/heroku-addons-not-recognizing-verified-account) to provision the add-on.

Comment: As an alternative, you could have signed up for a free SendGrid account using sendgrid.com and filled in the credentials manually.

Comment: @Swift - that's my approach. I don't want to use my credit card for a dev system, even if in theory it won't be charged. This way, in practice it won't be charged either :)

Comment: @Swift How to do that without adding the addon? can you refer to a link with the steps please?

Comment: @bero you would need to manually set SENDGRID_USERNAME and SENDGRID_PASSWORD using `heroku config:add SENDGRID_USERNAME=xxxx SENDGRID_PASSWORD=yyyy` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid