# ruby on rails tutorial ch 10 could get mail but links are wrong also Bitbucket could not add the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've **partially** solved this problem: I could get links with confirmation and resetting password.
The problem is that those links pointing to the **wrong** app and I need to adjust name of app manually in order to get the right redirection. Heroku representative said that those wrong address related to code....

1.Where in the Michael Harti ruby on rails tutorial could I find and change the code?

I've used Cloud 9 and Bitbucket as repository. I've created the new app on Bitbucket clone my existing app from Bitbucket to Cloud and want to push it to Bitbucket in order to make some changes.
But Bitbucket doesn't  allow me to do saying that there is the existing app. clone probably doesn't work in this case.

2.How to create exactly the same app as existing in Bitbucket but with different name on Cloud9 and push it to Bitbucket with different name?

thanks.

//config/environments/production.rb

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

host = 'tatyanaa.herokuapp.com'

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {

```
:address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',

:port           => '587',

:authentication => :plain,

:user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],

:password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],

:domain         => 'heroku.com',

:enable_starttls_auto => true
```

}

Comment: Where development.rb  is located in order me to make some changes? In normal situation I would not change anything but when I deployed  to heroku and click to send - it go nowhere - empty space/empty page...  Heroku representative  said that it is out of their scope. So, I need to make sure that mail is actually sent and then try to figure out why it doesn't send by heroku. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you see that output in console, it means your email was actually sent.

By "sent" I mean that Rails in development mode, instead of really sending the email (so you don't have to setup anything), it outputs it to the console like you can see there.

This configuration can be changed in `development.rb` by setting

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method    = :stmp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

You are then required to properly configure the smtp settings, check the [Action Mailer configuration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration) for additional details, should be something like:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method    = :stmp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:   "foo.bar.com",
  user_name: "someone",
  password:  "apassword"
}
```

However, I **highly suggest** you to keep the default configuration and let it log in console instead of sending real emails.

Comment: As you suggested I kept the default configuration but I still could not get mail in the production..... I've used setting as you show by hard copied user_name and password that I've got from command line.  Do you get them  by using command line or by providing credit card? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly write the code in `production.rb` ?
Here is mine (I've followed the same tutorial as well and it worked):

```
(production.rb)

....
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
host = 'my_heroku_app_name.herokuapp.com'
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
....
```

Also did you properly configure sendgrid as an addon on heroku?

```
(terminal window)
heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter
```

If you are stuck and REALLY don't know how to proceed, I recommend you to do the tutorial again from the start. It may seem inefficient to go through the same process again when (I assume) you haven't finished the entire tutorial itself. 
Believe me, I've also had the same situation where I "thought" I've followed the every step of the tutorial correctly before the app stopped working for some reason and when I restarted it again from the beginning and followed the steps again, this time with a more relaxed mind, the code worked perfectly :) And I've gone through the same tutorial "4 times" before I could finally "get it". I think it would be good for you if you repeat the same process again as it helps solidify your knowledge AND solve the problem.

Comment: I probably no enough  relaxed - that the main problem:)  I'll be more relaxed if you continue to give me some advices until end and not disappear:) Right now I am on ch9(went back a little bit) How the author get Figure 9.7?  I just got login without this  red color with warning "please login"

Comment: Disregard the previous: I've got this login with "please login". Also, I've completed ch9 - no errors , deployment and restarting heroku are fine.  I didn't see sense start from beginning if I have no errors and output correct until ch9.

Comment: I have exact the same product.rb as you show  - and it doesn't work for me. The page came out empty. ... But I don't  provide yet my credit card # as was suggested. Is  this the only one option to see the pages, to provide the credit card #? thanks.

Comment: Unless you provide your credit card number to heroku, the sendgrid addon will not work. But don't worry --- they won't charge you unless your application sends thousands of emails per day, which in your case will no be the case.

Comment: You can estimate what is my case as I could not estimate about your case. You only could guess.  Have you try not using credit card to make  send grid work?  I've tried but with not success. Let me know  if you could make ti work .................................................................................................................http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625754/adding-sendgrid-addon-to-my-heroku-django-app

Comment: I wouldn't know how to make it work without registering a credit card on heroku.

Comment: I have another question. I've add  Listing 11.25 but my output want not change from Figure 11.6 to Figure 11.7 - it is the same even so I add Listing 11.25.  If you have the right output could you show custom.css.css here or on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907542/ruby-on-rails-ch10-different-output-in-console-ch-11-dfferent-output