# ruby on rails: ch10: different output in console/ch 11 -dfferent output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have different output for ch 11 Michael Harti tutorial. 
Micro posts are located diagonally but not from top to button as shown on picture.
part of custom.css file as below from his tutorial:
What cause this not formatted output?

/* microposts 
.microposts {

list-style: none;

padding: 0;

li {

```
padding: 10px 0;
```

border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;

}

Answer (score 0):

On the same page in the tutorial, it says to create *this* method in the model...

```
private

  def create_activation_digest
    # Create the token and digest.
  end
```

It sounds like you didn't do that... or maybe you mis-spelled the method name.

Comment: I added this private  method but outpus is still not the same as on example. Is something wrong with /app/models/user.rb?

Comment: You fixed it!  The error is " NoMethodError: private method create_activation_digest'  which is exactly the error that Hartl said you should see.  You're fine. Now continue with the rest of the tutorial. :)

Comment: I've got as below pointing to some identity. Is it normal?                           $rails generate mailer UserMailer account_activation password_reset   identical  app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
   identical  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb

Comment: Are you asking a new question?  If so you can accept my answer if it helped and post the new question.

Comment: How to accept your answer, I mean where should i click to accept it?

Comment: If you look at the immediate left of my answer there's the answer rating and  up/down arrows and there should be an "accept" link there as well.

Comment: I accept your answer. Could you help me with ch10? When I've move from Listinng 10.39 to listing 10.40 - the fileld forgot had been lost... What to do about that?

Comment: from 10.38 to 10.39 - field password was lost. Any idea? thanks.

Comment: As I say you're asking a different question. Click in the option to accept my answer and ask a new question but we can't do repeated q and a in comments..

Comment: the new question(see link below). I've got 2 answers but no solutions yet:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818466/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-ch-10-could-not-get-mail